# Stop Windows 10 search on mapped drives returing UNC results

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, windows-10-v1909

[image]If I search, e.g. T:\Tools which is mapped to \server\tools, for sometool.exe, search results come back as finding the searched for file in UNC format like \server\tools\sometool.exe

This is a major pain and not how it has ever worked since, well, ever and didn't in Windows 10 1903 or earlier.

No registry tweaks, no third-party search tools and default settings in Explorer.

And, yes, has been "Googled" and DDG, etc.

Comment: My apologies for my answer. I do not see what the issue is. Perhaps see if you can provide a screen shot to help

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. If the current folder is `T:\Tools`, the search result should be in `T:`. The problem should only arrive when the current folder is `\\server\tools`.

Comment: @harrymc Correct in what you say, and as I wrote.  See new screencap - does not do so.  Returns UNC not drive letter.  Not searched from a UNC current folder, searched from, in the screencap example, S:\ ... different drive letter, same concept and result namely search results are not S: but UNC.

Comment: @John  see new screencap.

Comment: That was helpful. In Windows Explorer, in the Search Tab, click on and pull down:  Add Columns and Uncheck Folder Path. That column in your screen shot will go away.

Comment: @john Thanks, however shouldn't the path show the mapped location and not the UNC location?  If I want to tell a user "Go to T:\Software\etc.  that's a whole lot easier than telling them how to type a UNC.

Comment: I will keep looking. The display appears to be the way Explorer does it now.

Comment: Are you on Windows 10 1909? Troubleshooting:  `chkdsk` and also [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc Do you work for answers.microsoft.com?

Comment: @john Thanks for sticking with it.  Have an answer.  Change the "Folder Path" column to "Folder" and it becomes mapped, not UNC.  To retain that setting, close Explorer and next search respects the change.

Comment: That sounds fine.  Good luck with your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an answer. Change the "Folder Path" column to "Folder" and it becomes mapped, not UNC. To retain that setting, close Explorer and next search respects the change.